# How to fix error warning for unresolved import(which seems to be invalid warning)?

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pydev

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from configuration import config
from org.act.pages.HomePage import HomePageTabs

class VerifyTabs(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):  
        binary = FirefoxBinary(config.FIREFOX_BINARY_PATH)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=config.FIREFOX_PROFILE_PATH, firefox_binary=binary)
        self.homepage=HomePageTabs(self.driver)


    def test_home_page_tab(self):
        driver = self.driver
        homepage=self.homepage

        driver.get(config.APP_URL)
        .
        .
        .

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

In my PyDev project, I have created one folder as "configuration" and there is config.py file inside it. In my test class I am importing config.py file and reading data as shown in the code above(this is similar to Java properties file). My code works properly, but sometimes it shows error warning as Unresolved import:config at

> from configuration import config

But I observe if I delete the above line and write it once again, sometimes error warning disappear. Any idea why it happens only at this import statement?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screenshot of your pydev package explorer for that project?

When you run, does it always work?

Usually, I'd suggest you create a package for your own code (say: my_project) and put the things you want inside it to make sure it's not clashing with some other module you have installed on site-packages (i.e.: if you had some other `configuration` module in the site-packages).